# Grafana: avoid variable interpolation by escaping $

Tags: influxdb, grafana, grafana-templating

I have a query in Grafana for templating (against Influx) which has a tag which key contains the $ character.

How can I escape $ to avoid its interpolation with the variable?

Query:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "exdemon-analysis" WITH KEY = "analyzed_metric.attributes.$owner"
```

"analyzed_metric.attributes.$owner" is the key, $owner should not be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable name was also $owner, which makes Grafana replace the $owner string in the field.

Plus, it seems I hit a bug in Influx. It does not like the combination of "." and measurement name with "special characters" in my case "-".

With the following query and not having var with name $owner the problem was solved:

```
SHOW TAG VALUES FROM "exdemon_analysis" WITH KEY = "analyzed_metric.attributes.$owner"
```

Comment: I found this message helpful: "As long as you dont have a template variable named $owner nothing should be replaced."
https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/11359